# Laravel insert created and updated null

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'm saving multi records with insert but it is not adding created_at and updated_at it's null

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    CategoryUser::insert(
        collect($request->userId)
            ->crossJoin($request->categoryId)
            ->map(
                fn ($pair) => ['user_id' => $pair[0], 'category_id' => $pair[1]]
            )
            ->all()
    );
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

so how can i add created and update time() or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The `::insert()` method doesn't automatically apply `created_at` or `updated_at`. You have a couple options:

1. Loop and use the `create()` method:

```php
$data = collect($request->input('userId'))
  ->crossJoin($request->input('categoryId'));

foreach ($data as $categoryUser) {
  CategoryUser::create(
    ['user_id' => $categoryUser[0], 'category_id' => $categoryUser[1]]
  );
}
```

2. Manually map them:

```php
CategoryUser::insert(
  collect($request->input('userId'))
  ->crossJoin($request->input('categoryId'))
  ->map(fn ($pair) => [
    'user_id' => $pair[0],
    'category_id' => $pair[1],
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
  ])
  ->all()
);
```

(Don't forget to add `use Carbon\Carbon;` to the top of your Class)

Comment: Big thanks for help : )

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped you, please consider accepting this answer via the Check Mark next to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add migration so that it auto store current time.
in migration change field.
`$table->date('app_date')->default(DB::raw('NOW()'))`